# WebAPI returns corrupted, incomplete file

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, httpresponsemessage

I want to return an image from WebApi endpoint. This is my method:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetAttachment(string id)
{
    string dirPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Constants.ATTACHMENT_FOLDER);
    string path = string.Format($"{dirPath}\\{id}.jpg");

    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        var content = new StreamContent(stream);
        result.Content = content;
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = Path.GetFileName(path) };
        return result;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        _log.Warn($"Image {path} was not found on the server.");
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Invalid image ID");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the file that is downloaded is incomplete. The message in consuming Android app is:

> java.io.EOFException: source exhausted prematurely

Comment: How about adding `content-length` in the headers? `result.Content.Headers.Add(@"Content-Length", content.Length.ToString());`

Comment: that's because because `StreamContent` does not contain definition of `Length`

Comment: Correct, but try adding the header.

Comment: Tried adding the header and it was already being set to the correct value.  This smells like a bug in the StreamContent class or it's use somewhere down the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this was caused by compression, that was set for all responses in this controller. There is GZip encoding set up in controller's constructor:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(HttpContext.Current.Response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
```

To solve this, I added these lines to my method 
(just after beginning of `try` block):

```
// reset encoding and GZip filter
HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers["Content-Encoding"] = "";
HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers["Content-Type"] = "";    
// later content type is set to image/jpeg, and default is application/json
HttpContext.Current.Response.Filter = null;
```

Also, I'm setting content type and length like this:

```
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that your Android client thinks the download is over before it actually is.
To easily fix this, you can use this method instead which will return the entire file at once (rather than streaming it):

```
result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(path));
```

Comment: This is almost worthy of a downvote because of how bad this is!  If the file sizes are large, you will massively start using up memory.  Which is why I wound up looking for an answer to this same question!

Comment: @NormanH This is only one approach that works extremely well for small files